# How do you get started with setting up a local instance of Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

How do I get from the source code [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/) to a working system?

The README.md makes some configuration assumptions such as:

> The database can be brought up to date by running the
>   migrate.local.bat file in the Migrations directory. This assumes an
>   existing SQL Server database named DataExplorer with integrated
>   security enabled.

I've already downloaded the source and I have the tools required by the prerequisites.

Comment: It is entirely unclear what is blocking you - where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a dummies guide, I've downloaded the source, can I just press F5 and it's up and running?  the documentation assumes that I have an existing SQL server already setup, where is that documented?

Comment: Did you run the batch file? Did you create a database with the required name?

Comment: Since this is programming related, you're expected to fulfill the same requirements as Stack Overflow: what have you tried? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: IIRC I didn't had to change any of the sql scripts or .bat file to get the database up and running on my local sqlserver instance. So unless you have something different there it should run.

Comment: The problem is the lack of clear documentation for the uninitiated, there are no instructions on how the database should be created and/or configured, there are no instruction after having set up the database and run the script on what is then required.  Basically it's a documentation issue.  What I have or have not tried is not the question, it is "what are the steps necessary to get the application up and running?  assume that I want someone to create a dummies guide for me (or anyone else for that matter)

Comment: @Colin it's not meant for the uninitiated, probably, only for those knowing what they are doing to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the level of detail I would have liked, please feel free to add/update as necessary.  I've not yet covered importing the data dump.

1. Using git download/fork the repository from     https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer
2. Install the pre-requisite tools
3. Within SQL Server Management create a database 'DataExplorer' using the New Database Wizard
4. Modify the `StackExchange.DataExplorer\Migrations\migrate.local.bat`.  Change the line `..\Build\Migrator --connection="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DataExplorer;Integrated Security=True" PAUSE` 
   Setting the Data Source to match the Server name property of the database that you previous created
5. Run the `migrate.local.bat` file
6. Within SQ Server Management, load and run `StackExchange.DataExplorer\SeedData\sites.sql`
7. Create databases for all appropriate entries in `StackExchange.DataExplorer\SeedData\sites.sql`
8. Within Visual Studio, open the solution and edit `web.config`
9. Edit the following lines:

   ```
   <add name="AppConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DataExplorer;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="ReaderConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=!!DB!!;Integrated Security=True;" />
   ```

   Setting the Data Source again.

You should now be able to run the project, with no data imported.